# Wagtail / Using ListBlock without some atributes in mixin

Tags: django, wagtail

My mixin class:

```
class FeatureList(blocks.StructBlock):
    title = blocks.TextBlock(default=None, blank=True, null=True)
    description = blocks.ListBlock(blocks.TextBlock(default=None, blank=True, null=True))
    button_label = blocks.TextBlock(required=False, default=None, blank=True, null=True)
    button_url = blocks.URLBlock(required=False)
```

and my models

```
class ThreeListsBlock(DefaultFields, ThemeChooser, blocks.StructBlock):

    class Meta:
        icon = 'grip'

    tiles = blocks.ListBlock(FeatureList(), required=True)
```

How can i use in ThreeListsBlock attributes from FeatureList() without  button_url and button_label? I dont want creating copy FeatureList mixin.

I want see in ThreeListsBlock only title and description. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you create a `BasicList` that has title and description, and then extend that as `FeatureList`, which will also have `button_label` and `button_url`.

You can then specify `BasicList` in the `ThreeListsBlock` ListBlock field.

```
class BasicList(blocks.StructBlock):
    title = blocks.TextBlock(default=None, blank=True, null=True)
    description = blocks.ListBlock(blocks.TextBlock(default=None, blank=True, null=True))

class FeatureList(BasicList):
    button_label = blocks.TextBlock(required=False, default=None, blank=True, null=True)
    button_url = blocks.URLBlock(required=False)

class ThreeListsBlock(DefaultFields, ThemeChooser, blocks.StructBlock):
    tiles = blocks.ListBlock(BasicList(), required=True)
```